# plan9 official image won't boot raspberrypi

Tags: boot-issues

I downloaded http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/contrib/miller/9pi.img.gz and did

```
dd -bs=1M if="9pi.img" of="/dev/sdb"
```

and tried to boot the Pi with it but my monitor doesn't display anything. The LEDs on the Pi light up.

When I formatted sd card with sdformatter, copied all contents in the image's boot partition to it and tried to boot up the pi then on my monitor it displays a few messages which include `unable to find '/dev/sdk'` then reboots and go on.

The `/boot` partition contains:

```
9pi
9picpu
bootcode.bin
cmdline.txt
cmdline-cpu.txt
cmdline-demo.txt
cmdline-demo-net.txt
cmdline-term.txt
config.txt
fixup.dat
fixup_cd.dat
LICENCE
LICENCE.BROADCOM
LICENCE.LUCENT
start.elf
start_cd.elf
```

A guy with username arthos on http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/ mentioned that he managed to boot plan9 on Pi but he don't replies to my request there.

Has anyone managed to boot Plan9 on their Raspberry Pi?

Comment: are you sure it's supposed to show anything on TV? might as well boot using serial console or something similar.

Comment: @lenik I don't have a TV or serial usb cable :(

Comment: After you dd'ed the 9pi.img to the sd card, what did the /boot partition contain?  What partitions existed on the sd card?

Comment: "my monitor don't even twitch" -- could you please describe your setup, how did you connect the monitor to the Pi?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn sd card contain a small fat 32 boot partition and remaining `Plan 9` partition. the boot partition got files like `9pi`, `9picpu`, `bootcode.bin`, `cmdline.txt`, `cmdline-cpu.txt`, `cmdline-demo.txt`, `cmdline-demo-net.txt`, `cmdline-term.txt`, `config.txt`, `fixup.dat`, `fixup_cd.dat`, `LICENCE`, `LICENCE.BROADCOM`, `LICENCE.LUCENT`, `start.elf` and `start_cd.elf`

Comment: Can you post the contents of `cmdline.txt` and also all of the other `cmdline` files?  I wonder if Plan9 us booting up, but doesn't use the video display to display messages.  Perhaps the contents of the cmdline files will lead to some clues about what is going on.

Comment: @lenik my setup Pi-HDMI->HDMI-VGA->VGA-Monitor. NOOBS SD card worked well with this setup.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn `cmdline.txt` has `readparts=1 nobootprompt=local user=glenda`

Comment: @HeatfanJohn no more suggestions? I bought the Pi to try out plan9..

Comment: It is possible that Plan9 only outputs to the serial port.  You may need to use [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/954) type of cable to connect to the Pi's UART.  How big is the SD card you used so I can try this on my Pi?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn have you tried plan 9 on your SD card? Do U've success?

Comment: connecting TV with video out to pi worked! May be plan 9 don have hdmi support.